# Hide comment count from wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, css

Hello I am trying to get rid of the 'leave a comment' or 'n comments' tag which is shown on my wordpress website recent posts without getting rid of Date and Author

Any solution?

Comment: Update the template or use a dash of CSS. Google is your friend with this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, have a look if your theme 'wordstar' has a configuration option for this meta-data. If not, you could hide what you do not need using custom CSS:

```
.entry-meta .comment,
.entry-meta .cat-links,
.entry-meta .tag-links {
 display: none;
}
```

Just add whatever you want to hide.

Comment: Unfortunately the theme doesnt have any configuration for this, also I tried hiding it using custom CSS as you mentioned, still no luck. Even in the php files there is no exact method mentioned which builds this

Comment: Yes, the theme's CSS has a high specificity:
`#main .hentry.post-content .entry-meta ul li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}`
My CSS snippet's specificity was not high enough.

I hate using !important rules, but to keep it short and easy you could just write:

.entry-meta .comment,
.entry-meta .cat-links,
.entry-meta .tag-links {
 display: none !important;
}

Comment: @DanielSixl OP can use the same selector as the themes. Just has to come after. No need for `!important`.

Comment: @hungerstar That's why I wrote "to keep it short and easy"!

Comment: @DanielSixl I know you did, but it's that important to avoid `!important`. :P

Comment: Mind that you can use the overwhelmingly long `#main .hentry.post-content .entry-meta ul li { }` selector to avoid the `!important` statement ;)

Answer (score 0):

Disable comments. Go to `WP Admin -> Settings -> Discussion ->`, uncheck **Allow people to post comments on new articles** checkbox and click <kbd>Save</kbd> button.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the comments count from your WordPress blog, add a CSS rule to hide the `.comments-count` class. To do so, go to `/wp-admin > Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS` and place the following CSS rule:

```
.comments-count {
    display: none;
}
```